# If I have that $X,Y,Z$ are jointly independent random variables, how can I show that $X$ is independent of $YZ$ (the product)?

Tags: probability, statistics

I read in a book that gave without proof that if I have that $X,Y,Z$ are jointly independent, then $X \perp cYZ$, where $\perp$ means independent of and $c$ is a finite constant. How can I show this fact from a measure theoretic or even simpler way? thanks!

Comment: Show that $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y,Z)$ are independent, where $\sigma(X)$ denotes sigma algebra generated by $X$

Comment: @user160738 Good job finding my question :))